# Powershell - Add-Adgroupmember objectclass:contact to a distribution group error Cannont find[..]

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0, active-directory-group

I'm working on a simple script that should add a contact to a distribution group depending of the week of the year. My bug is that my script can add `objectclass:User` but when I try with a contact GUID the script give me that error:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: '123dd2345-12f0-542b-c3e6-5774bac431aa' under: 'DC=MY,DC=DOMAIN'.
At line:1 char:25
+ get-adgroup $ADGroup |  Add-ADGroupMember  -members $zvar.ObjectGUID
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (123dd2345-12f0-542b-c3e6-5774bac431aa:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

The part of the script that I use is looking like that:

```
$zvar = get-adobject -filter {displayname -eq "Valentine, John (CELL)" } #this is my contact displayname that is put in a variable with necessary properties
get-adgroup "Dist - Support group" | Add-ADGroupMember  -members $zvar.ObjectGUID #this is my Distribution group, whatever the properties I put to my contact object I get the error message above i.e. $zvar.name, $zvar.distinguishedname, etc
```

If I replace the value  "Valentine, John (CELL)" by the ObjectClass:user "Valentine,John" the command will succeed without error.

Am I using the command correctly ? 
I could probably use the Quest-module but I'd like to avoid using a third party.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error seems to indicate it's looking for a security principal, which implies the group your trying to add to is a security group rather than a distribution group.

Comment: I just check and the groupcategory value is "Distribution"

Comment: Might have better luck using the Exchange cmdlets, then.

Comment: Yea that's what I find out too. Unfortunately this is not an option to me. I'll have to use the last resort solution which is Quest-module.

Answer (score 6):

Came across this problem as well today: You cannot add an AD Object of class `"objectClass=contact"` to a group using the `Add-ADGroupMember` cmdlet.

However, the members of a an AD group are simply stored in the multivalued property "member", and every `*-ADObject` and related command supports the `-Add`, `-Replace`, `-Clear` and `-Replace` parameters.

Thus, this works to add a single user:

```
Set-ADGroup -Identity "GroupName" -Add @{'member'=$contact.DistinguishedName};
```

And this removes the user:

```
Set-ADGroup -Identity "GroupName" -Remove @{'member'=$contact.DistinguishedName};
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you for posting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

As @mjolinor comment, the exchange cmdlet would be the solution, but I don't have what it need to use it. So I will use Quest-cmdlet. With that it's working.